# Extend tag of a composed Go Struct

Tags: go, struct, go-gorm

I have two structs:

```
// package a -- third party library
type UserProps struct {
  FirstName `json:"first_name"`
  LastName `json:"last_name"`
}

// package b -- my own package
type User struct {
  a.UserProps
}
```

The problem is that UserProps is inherited from a 3rd party library, so I can't change its source code.

My question is can I extend the `FirstName` tag from within the `User` struct in package b so that the tag would eventually be as such `json:"first_name",sql:"unique_index"` ?

Also, note that I only want to extend the tag of only one field, FirstName.

Comment: why don't you create that struct in your `b` package?

Comment: @GujaratSantana - because it's a third party library that comes with its own tags and struct methods.

Comment: Have you tried adding the property and shadowing the embedded one? ```
type User struct {
  a.UserProps
  FirstName `json:"first_name",sql:"unique_index"` 
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to do something like subclassing, treating the JSON marshaling as if it's an abstract method to be mixed in, but go doesn't really let you express such things. If you really don't want to follow Gujarat's suggestion, you can try to solve this with `go generate` or you could implement a `MarshalJSON` method for your `User` type that uses reflection to replicate the standard behavior of `json.Marshal` in a way that handles your scenario.